# Unset a variable without checking whether it has been already used or declared

Tags: php

To unset a variable without cheking whether it has been already used or declared.Which is valid in PHP: (a) or (b)? Although both works. In the sample code below,forward referencing is used,how PHP handles it internally?

(a)

```
while(stmt1->fetch())
{
   unset($data);
   $i=0;
   while(stmt2->fetch())
   {
     //Some code.......
     $data[$i] = $some_Value;
     $i++;
   }
}
```

(b)

```
while(stmt1->fetch())
{
   if(isset($data))
   {
     unset($data);
   }
   $i=0;
   while(stmt2->fetch())
   {
     //Some code.......
     $data[$i] = $some_Value;
     $i++;
   }
}
```

Comment: It is incredibly rare that you have to use `unset()`. Are you sure you have to do so in this case? From your code it looks like it is not necessary at all.

Comment: actually I use $data to pass it to another function every time the outer loop iterates, if I really don't unset the array,the previous data elements will create a mess! @SverriM.Olsen

Comment: Instead of unsetting the variable you should just set the `$data` variable to an empty array, like so: `$data = array();`.

Comment: Well! I am curious to know just one thing about the fact that when $data is initialized to an empty array each time the loop iterates,what about the memory previously allocated to $data? Does PHP automatically handles it (i mean to say something like garbage collection) ?

Comment: PHP is fully garbage collected (it is done automatically). The `unset()` function just destroys the variable from your script; it does not have anything to do with garbage collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of unsetting the variable, set it with an initial value. This conveys the intention much clearer.

Also, you don't need to keep track of `$i` to insert a new element:

```
while ($stmt1->fetch()) {
    $data = []; //Initialize empty array. This is PHP 5.4+ syntax.
    while ($stmt2->fetch()) {
        $data[] = $someValue; //$array[] means "Push new element to this array"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Second Rikudo!! I am curious to ask just one thing about the fact that when $data is initialized to an empty array each time the loop iterates,what about the memory previously allocated to $data? Does PHP automatically handles it (i mean to say something like garbage collection) ?

Answer (score 2):

Method **B** is not neccessary. If you unset a non-existing variable nothing will happen, you won't get an undefined variable error.

You can see this behaviour [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b032dcdee9062d6184947412d338b7a568ec7d19) (it has `error_reporting(E_ALL)`).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you see it is some other code, I've already seen something like the following code (It's not the real code, only to give an idea of the use case).

The isset what used like "isset and with validated value". I'm not saying it's good practice (of course it's not, and even worse in this simplified example), it's just to show that, with overloaded magic methods, it may have some sense.

```
class unsetExample {

  private $data = 'some_value';

  public function __isset($name) {
    if ($this->${name} != 'my_set_value') {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
  }

  public function __unset($name) {
    unset($this->${name});
    echo 'Value unset';
  }

}

$u = new unsetExample;

if (isset($u->data)) {
  unset($u->data);
} else {
  echo 'In that case I don\'t want to unset, but I will do something else instead';
}
```

Edit :  Changed the code, it's much more how it was is the real code now